# Permutation for a random number excluding leading zero

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, python-3.x, permutation

I know there are tons of examples for getting the permutation for a given number however i couldn't figure out how to implement it without taking into account the leading 0.

So my use case is like this:

given a number - say 240(the input range is 1, 1000000), i would like to see the output without 24, 42 (numbers which has a leading 0)

Below is what i did using python

```
>>> digits = [int(x) for x in str(240)]
>>> n_digits = len(digits)
>>> n_power = n_digits - 1
>>> permutations = itertools.permutations(digits)
>>> values = [v * (10**(n_power - i)) for i, v in enumerate(itertools.repeat(1, n_digits))]
>>> positions = list(xrange(n_digits))
>>> [sum(item[x] * values[x] for x in positions) for item in permutations]
[240, 204, 420, 402, 24, 42]
>>>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Note that `int(024) == 20` in Python 2.x, but you could `str.lstrip('0')`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - already known but acknowledged, thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### to see the output without 24, 42 (numbers which has a leading 0)

```
>>> aRawLIST = [sum(item[x] * values[x] for x in positions) for item in permutations]

>>> [ aTruePOS for aTruePOS in aRawLIST if len( str( aTruePOS ) ) > 2 ]
[240, 204, 420, 402]
```

In general, may state `len( str( aTruePOS ) ) == len( str( anInputNUMBERasInteger ) )`

---

Upon DanyC's objection:

> you solution works but only if the input number is in range(10, 1000000). if you try with str('40') won't show you anything –  DanyC 9 mins ago

---

```
>>> def aTest( anInputNUMBERasInteger ):
...     digits       = [ int( x ) for x in str( anInputNUMBERasInteger ) ]
...     n_digits     = len( digits )
...     n_power      = n_digits - 1
...     permutations = itertools.permutations( digits )
...     values       = [ v * ( 10 ** ( n_power - i ) ) for i, v in enumerate( itertools.repeat( 1, n_digits ) ) ]
...     positions    = list( xrange( n_digits ) )
...     raw          = [ sum( item[x] * values[x] for x in positions ) for item in permutations ]
...     return [ aTruePOS for aTruePOS in raw if len( str( aTruePOS ) ) == len( str( anInputNUMBERasInteger ) ) ]
...
>>> aTest( 240 )
[240, 204, 420, 402]
>>> aTest( 2400 )
[2400, 2400, 2040, 2004, 2040, 2004, 4200, 4200, 4020, 4002, 4020, 4002]
>>> aTest( 24 )
[24, 42]
>>> aTest( 40 )
[40]
>>> aTest(  5 )
[5]
>>> aTest(  1 )
[1]
```

### Q.E.D.

Comment: you solution works but only if the input number is in range(10, 1000000). if you try with str('40') won't show you anything

Comment: As tested and re-tested, **solution works correctly in the whole range( 1, ... ) as given by the Original Post. Q.E.D.**

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
>>> num = 240
>>> permutations = itertools.permutations(str(num))
>>> values = [int(''.join(c)) for c in permutations if (''.join(c))[0] != '0']
>>> values
>>> [240, 204, 420, 402]
```

EDIT:

```
>>> values = [int(''.join(c)) for c in permutations]
>>> [c for c in values if c >= 10 ** (len(str(n)) - 1 ) ]
```

Comment: this is tidy however my fear/ reason why i didn't go in first place with this simplified solution is due to performance in case num is a big value

Comment: @DanyC the modification done will shorten the time required to something (perhaps quicker based on the quick timing test I did).

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing to do is to remove all numbers from the list that are less than 10^(k-1) (where k is the size of input.

Add these two lines:

```
threshold = pow(10,n_digits-1)

[x for x in [sum(item[x] * values[x] for x in positions) for item in permutations] if x>=threshold]
```